# How can I exclude multiple folders from search in linux?

Tags: linux

How can I exclude multiple folders from search in linux? In the folder  "home/Stand" i use the command to search:

i use the command to search:

```
find ./ -name "fesb-6.2.1.1.tar.gz"
```

I am getting a lot of results from unnecessary folders in this directory, how can I exclude multiple folders from search?

```
find ./ -name fesb-6.2.1.1.tar.gz -not -path "6.2.1-pbo" did not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give a try, it should work:

```
find ./ -name fesb-6.2.1.1.tar.gz ! -path '*6.2.1-pbo*'
```

Comment: Nice solution ! The only problem is performance-related. `find` still gets into `'*6.2.1-pbo*'` directories and processes all the files in them.